# Am I putting the right limits of the integral?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, jacobian, iterated-integrals

[image]

Let:

\begin{align}
r&=\sqrt{a^2 + p^2 - 2ap \cos \theta}\\
s&=a\\
t&=p\\
f(r) &= \text{continuous function of } r\\
g(s) &= \text{continuous function of } s\\
\end{align}

Consider the expression:

\begin{align}
\int_{q'}^q \int_{b'}^b g(s)\ \int_{s-t}^{s+t} f(r)\ dr\ ds\ dt\
\end{align}

We next have to change the variables from $(r,s,t)$ to $(\theta, a, p)$

The Jacobian of the coordinate transformation (after computing) is:

$J= \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}=\dfrac{a\ p\ \sin\theta}{r}$

Thus our new function becomes $J\ f(r) =\dfrac{a\ p\ \sin\theta}{r} f(r)$

> **Question:**
>
> One of my friends said that the limits of the integration would be as follows:
>
> \begin{align}
> \int_{q'}^q \int_{b'}^b g(a)\ \int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac{a\ p\ \sin\theta}{r} f(r) \ d \theta\ da\ dp\
> \end{align}
>
> Is he correct?

Comment: What is the value of $r$ when $\theta = 0$? is it $s - t = a - p$? What is the value of $r$ when $\theta = \pi$? Is it $s + t = a + p$? Your friend is on the right track, but not sufficiently cautious. (Or else, there is more information about $s,t$ that you didn't reproduce here.)

Comment: Yes, it is $s - t = a - p$. Yes, it is $s + t = a + p$.

Comment: What if $a = 3, p = 5$?

Comment: Even though I know something about how to apply limits while *changing the integration order*, I don't know the rules for applying limits while **changing variables of multiple integrals**

Comment: You learned those rules first, before you ever saw multivariable calculus. Don't forget them. And (because your reply is a little unclear to me), remember my question is "what is $r$ when $\theta = 0, \theta = \pi$?", not "what is $s-t, s+t$?"

Comment: What if $a=3,p=5?$........ then $\int_{-2}^8$ Or, is there any problem? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Oh I see.... The function $\dfrac{a\ p\ \sin\theta}{r} f(r) \$ will not be integrable.

Comment: Answer to you first question:$ r(\theta=0)= s−t=a−p$ & $r(\theta=\pi)= s+t=a+p$

Comment: The function is integrable (being complex does not make the function unintegrable), but $r \ne 3 - 5$ Without some restrictions on $q, q', b, b'$, the limits do not necessarily work. But when you can guarantee that $a \ge |p|$, your friend is correct.

Comment: Sorry sir, hundreds of apologies... It was **given** that $p$ is positive (always) and $a>p$ all over the domain of integral. Let me add a diagram in the question.

Comment: That is alright - I pointed out the possibility. In this case your friend is correct.